# Installing v. 12.04.2 graphics card not recognized chrome9

Tags: 12.04, vga, via

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 on my home PC which previously ran XP, this computer isn't a dual boot, I opted to remove windows. Install seemed to go without a hitch until I went to reboot, computer froze with the CD still in the disc tray. I removed the disc and manually rebooted.

Unfortunately my graphics card isn't being recognized. Through some internet searching I've been able to find out the model of graphics card I have.
By using:

```
lshw -c display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: k8m89OCE/k8n89oce [Chrome9]
vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
version: 11
width: 32 bits
clock: 66MHz
capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=64 mingnt=2
resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:de000000-de00ffff
```

I've tried using:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
```

..and it says:

```
the following packages have unmet dependencies:
xserver-xorg-video-openchrome : 
Depends: xorg-video-abi-11
Depends: xserver-xorg-core (. 2:1.10.99.901)
```

I've also tried:

```
sudo X :1 -configure
```

and it says Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices. Configuration failed.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the missing dependencies with:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-video-abi-11
```

And rebooted.

Everything works now.